# How to get same model and prediction in scikit-learn 0.17.1 and 0.22.1?

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn, data-science

My current code is written on python2.7 using scikit-learn 0.17.1 . I am trying to move to latest versions of python3.7 and scikit-learn 0.22.1 . For the exact same feature set, my model object after calling .fit is different. The values of coeff_ are not matching at all. As a result my predictions are also not matching. Is this expected?

This is a big code rewrite exercise and I need to test finally that my changes are working perfectly.

My initial test plan was to compare predictions for exact same values between old code and new code. But if predictions are going to be different, I will have to check that predictions accuracy has improved in the new code. I would still be not sure if I have missed some transformations.

If you have faced similar problem, please advice what you did in such a scenario.

here is the code I am using which is same in 0.17.1 and 0.22.1 -

```
model = ElasticNetCV(l1_ratio=[0.5, 0.75, 0.95, 0.99, 1.0], normalize=True, n_jobs=1)
model.fit(features.values, targets.values)
```

Comment: Might be normal that the results are different after algorithms updates. Plus, there is also the fact that the random shuffling for train/test separation and order for the training inputs might change.

Maybe there is no need to be worried. Did you check the results on test side? Is it better than before or similar?

Comment: @ThomasZwetyenga, I also doubt the same thing. It is not random shuffling atleast, cause results within version are consistently same. They are different only across versions. even if results are better, it becomes much more difficult to prove better than to prove they are same.

Comment: I think it is a valid question. If model and prediction changes in new versions, how can someone make sure nothing has gone wrong in version upgrades. please reopen the question.